# How to load value of GOLD from xml file?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I work on asp.net core 6 razor view . I face issue I can't get value of GOLD `003` on asp.net core 6 application

Name of file `DfaultValues.xml`

and content as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<defaultvalues>
    
        
    <UserDetails>
        <UserID>9595</UserID>
        <UserName>Aweer User</UserName>
        <UserType>PY</UserType>
        <Branch>A</Branch>
        <BranchCode>10206</BranchCode>
        <BranchDesc></BranchDesc>
        <BranchType>B</BranchType>
        <BusinessUnit>Jumeira</BusinessUnit>
        <CompanyNo>00001</CompanyNo>
        <CompanyName>Union Co-Operative Society</CompanyName>
    </UserDetails>
    <configuration>
        <LPAPPID></LPAPPID>
        <LPSQLPY>101</LPSQLPY>
        <LPJDEPY>807</LPJDEPY>
        <LPSQLPD>102</LPSQLPD>
        <LPJDEPD>310</LPJDEPD>
        <PRINTERIP>172.17.0.53</PRINTERIP>
        <PRINTERNAME>Black4</PRINTERNAME>
        <TEMPCONFIG>Config.temp</TEMPCONFIG>
        <GOLD>003</GOLD>
        <SILVER>002</SILVER>
        <GREEN>01</GREEN>
        <BLACK>004</BLACK>
        <NORMAL>001</NORMAL>
    </configuration>
</defaultvalues>
```

my model on razor app asp.net core

```
public class XMLInfo
    {
      
        public string GOLD { get; set; }
       
     }
```

So How to load file on `program.cs`

and How to get value of gold on page load color

```
page loadcolor.html.cs

public class loadcolor : PageModel
    {
public void OnGet()
{
// how to get color Gold value 003
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for support suppose this  file goldfile.xml and i need to get it from write it static so how to change my code to search for file goldfile.xml and read content without write static path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the detailed steps I shared, and I can get the value of `GOLD`.

**Test Result**

[image]

**gold.cshtml**

```
@page "/gold"
@model IdentityTest.Pages.goldModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Load Color</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Color: @Model.GoldValue</h1>
</body>
</html>

@{
}
```

**gold.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Xml;

namespace IdentityTest.Pages
{
    public class goldModel : PageModel
    {
        public string? GoldValue { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            string filePath = "wwwroot/xml/goldFile.xml"; // Replace with the actual path to your XML file

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(filePath);

            XmlNode goldNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/GOLD");
            GoldValue = goldNode.InnerText;
        }
    }
}
```

**The structure of my project contents**

[image]